# Is it appropriate to say "Per my teacher" instead of "According to my teacher"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

One meaning of *[per](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per)* is **according to** *per* Merriam-Webster:

> according to —often used with *as* • ***per*** instructions • *as **per** usual*

Can I use *per* in the following way?

> Per my teacher

Please note that the original title of the question was:
Is *per* always interchangeable with *according to*?

Comment: No. My car gets 30 miles according to gallon.  (This is in answer to the question in the title)

Comment: @Jim: If that's *according to your Volkswagen‎ car*, I'd take the claim with a pinch of salt!

Comment: The 'according to' sense is far less commonly used than is 'according to'. Try Google searches on "according to her" and "per her".

Comment: British English does not generally use *per* in the sense of *according to,* whether used with a person "Per my teacher" or another noun "Per your instructions". The latter might be more commonly expressed "As per your instructions," although the former would never be said with *as.*

Comment: Shouldn't your title be "Is 'per' always interchangeable with 'according to' when it carries this sense?"?

Comment: My original question was poorly stated. I have revised it thanks to your comments.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I guess "take the claim with a pinch of salt" is some kind of joke or sarcasm, but what is the point of whole sentence? Does it mean it is not reasonable or feasible to calculate miles by gallon?

Comment: @WXJ96163: I guess the "in joke" there was because *at the time*, Volkswagen were in the news on account of having been exposed for deliberately designing their Engine Management Software to mislead trading standards emissions tests. We usually calculate *miles **per** gallon* (I can't think of a context where *miles **by** gallon* is likely).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thanks for your correction. I guess I could have said "to calculate miles by counting how many gallons has been used" while "miles per gallon" could be a statistic or a unit of measurement to describe that statistic? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Jim Does your comment mean that "according to my teacher" is incorrect?

Comment: @WXJ96163: I'm sure it must have happened *at some time*, but it would be very unusual "to calculate miles by counting how many gallons **have been used**!" The only context where that would make sense if if you knew ***exactly*** how much fuel had been used, ***and*** you knew an accurate value for how many miles your vehicle should do to the gallon! Most people would just zeroise the trip meter before startiing the drive, and just ***read*** the mileage rather than "calculate" it. Or note the initial odometer reading and subtract that from the final reading, for a "calculation".

Comment: @WXJ96163 - No.  As noted at the bottom of the question, the original title was “Is *per* ***always*** interchangeable with *according to*.   I was providing an example that shows “not always”

Answer (score 4):

You have identified only one definition of 'per'. There are three current, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per):

1. by means of
2. with respect to every member of a group
3. according to

The use you identified is the third on that list. Examples of the first ("per bearer") are now considered archaic, but the second ("miles per gallon" or "one plate per person")  is quite common, and both are distinct from the third.

Comment: Good point. I shall adjust